# Efficient way to copy over production data to test DB for PHPUnit tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, yii, phpunit

Before unit tests are run, the test DB needs to have all dependent data copied over. In this particular test I need to run, there is data spread over 12 tables that the called methods within the tests will depend on.

When the tests are run, I need to make sure the test database gets populated with the same values from production for these test cases.

Is there a streamlined efficient way of doing this or do I have to manually copy over each row from each table before running the tests?

I'm using Yii 1.1 with PHPUnit 4.6.

Comment: You can use migration

Answer (score 0):

You can easily define a proper migration and apply them when you need.

You can use migration up and migrationdown for prepare the DB you need for all your test